# How to create a query object with Func / Expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, expression, nest, func

I want to create a reusable query object for my project that uses ElasticSearch. I am already using a similar [QueryObject from the Generic Unit of Work/Repositories](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Repository.Pattern.Ef6/QueryObject.cs) by LongLe for queries against the database using Entity Framework.

I can't really seem to wrap my head around exactly how to do this - I'm not sure how to "chain" the parts of the lambda expression together. I've tried using Expression/Func but this is a new area for me that I do not fully understand. I feel as though I'm just stabbing in the dark.

Since I don't even know exactly how to word my question, here's an example of what I am currently doing, what I am trying to do, and my progress so far:

**What I currently have to do:**

```
    ISearchResponse<DemoIndexModel> result = client.Search<DemoIndexModel>(s => s.Query(
        q => q.Term(t => t.FirstName, firstName)
        && q.Term(t => t.LastName, lastName)));
```

**What I would like to do:**

```
    var query = new DemoIndexQuery();
    query = query.ByFirstName(firstName);
    query = query.ByLastName(lastName);

    result = client.Search<DemoIndexModel>(s => s.Query(query.Compile()));
```

**Code so far:**

```
public abstract class ElasticQueryObject<T> where T : class
    {
        private Func<QueryDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer> _query;

        // tried using Expression, still completely lost
        private Expression<Func<QueryDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>> _expression;

        public Func<QueryDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer> Compile()
        {
            return _query;
        }

        public Func<QueryDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer> And(Func<QueryDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer> query)
        {
            if (_query == null)
            {
                _query = query;
            }
            else
            {
                // how do I chain the query??? I only can figure out how to set it.
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DemoIndexQuery : ElasticQueryObject<DemoIndexModel>
    {
        public DemoIndexQuery ByFirstName(string firstName)
        {
            And(p => p.Term(term => term.FirstName, firstName));

            return this;
        }

        public DemoIndexQuery ByLastName(string lastName)
        {
            And(p => p.Term(term => term.LastName, lastName));

            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Apart from the fact that you're not returning the modified query, I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're breaking the LINQ contract. The query should be immutable - all the methods operating on the query should return a new query instead of modifying the old one. Due to the way the query is built, this is intrinsically composable, so instead of

```
public DemoIndexQuery ByFirstName(string firstName)
{
    And(p => p.Term(term => term.FirstName, firstName));

    return this;
}
```

you can just use this:

```
public DemoIndexQuery ByFirstName(string firstName)
{
    return Where(p => p.Term(term => term.FirstName, firstName));
}
```

If this is not possible for some reason, you'll need to handle building the expression tree yourself, before you pass it forward. The simplest way would be something like this:

```
Expression<...> oldQuery = ...;
var newCondition = (Expression<...>)(p => p.Term(...));

return Expression.And(oldQuery, newCondition);
```

If your query provider doesn't support this, you'll need a bit more work - you can build the whole where predicate yourself separately, and then make sure you fix the lambdas and lambda parameters.

Comment: The Query Object isn't the part that doesn't work, I'm trying to understand how to chain the parts of the expression. And I don't have a `Where()` option. How exactly do I build an expression tree for a Func<>?

Comment: @DoctorOreo `Expression<Func<...>>` is a lambda expression - you create it with `Expression.Lambda`. The tricky part is mapping the lambda arguments properly - you need to use the same `ParameterExpression` in the declaration *and* each of the uses later.